# Linking Azure Kinect libraries to ROS2 workspace

Tags: c++, cmake, ros2, azurekinect

I work on Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS 2 Foxy. I am trying to make a node that could use Azure Kinect libraries that I previously installed. The libraries are located in `/usr/include`.
In compiling my code, I get an error that tells me that colcon build cannot find these libraries. I searched on the Internet and apparently this is an issue with Kinect libraries.
However, to the best of my knowledge, there is no example of ROS 2 package that runs an Azure Kinect. Consequently, I am trying to adapt the content of a ROS 1 package I found (https://github.com/microsoft/Azure_Kinect_ROS_Driver).
When I compile my adaptation through colcon build, I come across the following error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/Findk4a.cmake:22 (message):
   Error: Azure Kinect SDK Version numbers contain exactly 3 components (major.minor.rev). Requested number of components:
```

The CMakeLists.txt files requires other CMake files, that I report below:

- my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(acquisition_block)

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem thread)

add_executable(skeleton_capture src/skeleton_capture.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(skeleton_capture rclcpp std_msgs)

##install(TARGETS skeleton_capture
 ## DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})


#target_include_directories(include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})


############################
#### AZURE KINECT SDK ######
############################

message("Finding K4A SDK binaries")

# Disable cached locations for K4A SDK binaries.
# Do this to force the search logic to happen correctly.
# If we don't disable these cached directories, we
# won't be able to tell the difference between the ext/sdk location
# and the system installed version on linux. Since we have to treat these
# differently (one needs install, one doesn't) we must disable the cache
# so that find_package(k4a) will fail in all cases if not installed via the .deb.
unset(k4a_DIR CACHE)

# Force running the Findk4a.cmake module
include(~/phd_ws/src/acquisition_block/cmake/Findk4a.cmake)

find_package(k4a REQUIRED)
if (k4abt_FOUND)
  set(K4A_LIBS k4a::k4a)
else()
  message("Basic k4a libraries not found!")
endif()

find_package(k4arecord REQUIRED)
if (k4abt_FOUND)
  list(APPEND K4A_LIBS k4a::k4arecord)
else()
  message("Recording k4a libraries not found!")
endif()

# Try to find and enable the body tracking SDK
find_package(k4abt REQUIRED)
if (k4abt_FOUND)
  list(APPEND K4A_LIBS k4abt::k4abt)
  message(STATUS "Body Tracking SDK found: compiling support for Body Tracking")
  message("Body tracking libraries found!")
  ##target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PUBLIC K4A_BODY_TRACKING)
  ##target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME}_nodelet PUBLIC K4A_BODY_TRACKING)
else()
  message("!!! Body Tracking SDK not found: body tracking features will not be available !!!")
endif()

include(~/phd_ws/src/acquisition_block/cmake/Installk4a.cmake)

##################################
###### END AZURE KINECT SDK ######
##################################

#target_include_directories(skeleton_capture include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

ament_target_dependencies(skeleton_capture
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
  ${K4A_LIBS}
  )


ament_package()
```

- the `Findk4a.cmake`

```
include(~/phd_ws/src/acquisition_block/cmake/FindModuleHelpers.cmake)

set(RELATIVE_WIN_LIB_DIR "sdk/windows-desktop/amd64/release/lib")
set(RELATIVE_WIN_BIN_DIR "sdk/windows-desktop/amd64/release/bin")

set(RELATIVE_WIN_K4A_LIB_PATH "${RELATIVE_WIN_LIB_DIR}/k4a.lib")
set(RELATIVE_WIN_K4A_DLL_PATH "${RELATIVE_WIN_BIN_DIR}/k4a.dll")

set(RELATIVE_WIN_K4ARECORD_LIB_PATH "${RELATIVE_WIN_LIB_DIR}/k4arecord.lib")
set(RELATIVE_WIN_K4ARECORD_DLL_PATH "${RELATIVE_WIN_BIN_DIR}/k4arecord.dll")

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Windows")
    set(DEPTHENGINE_GLOB "depthengine_*.dll")
elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Linux")
    set(DEPTHENGINE_GLOB "libdepthengine.so.*")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
endif()

# K4A versions have exactly 3 components: major.minor.rev
if (NOT (FIND_VERSION_COUNT EQUAL 3))
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Error: Azure Kinect SDK Version numbers contain exactly 3 components (major.minor.rev). Requested number of components: ${FIND_VERSION_COUNT}")
endif()

# First, check the ext/sdk folder for a depth engine. ALWAYS DO THIS FIRST.
# We must not run "find_package(k4a)" until we are certain that we can use
# the ext/sdk folder. Otherwise, the k4a::k4a target will 
# override any attempts to later create a new imported k4a::k4a target.
unset(_depthengine_bin)
file(GLOB_RECURSE _depthengine_bin 
    LIST_DIRECTORIES FALSE 
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/sdk/*${DEPTHENGINE_GLOB}")

if(NOT _depthengine_bin)
    quiet_message(STATUS "Could not find depth engine in ./ext/sdk! Rejecting ext/sdk")
else()
    find_package(k4a ${FIND_VERSION} ${_exact_arg} ${_quiet_arg} NO_MODULE NO_DEFAULT_PATH PATHS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/sdk")
    find_package(k4arecord ${FIND_VERSION} ${_exact_arg} ${_quiet_arg} NO_MODULE NO_DEFAULT_PATH PATHS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/sdk")

    if(${k4a_FOUND} AND ${k4arecord_FOUND})
        set(K4A_INSTALL_NEEDED TRUE)

        quiet_message(STATUS "Found an Azure Kinect SDK in ./ext/sdk")

        # Add the depth engine as an IMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES to ensure it gets copied
        set_property(TARGET k4a::k4a PROPERTY IMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES "${_depthengine_bin}") 
        
        # If we found a valid SDK in ext/sdk, this always overrides anything we might find in the system path.
        # k4a_FOUND should have been set by find_package(k4a), so return now.
        quiet_message(STATUS "Accepted SDK in ./ext/sdk. System paths will not be searched")
        return()
    else()
        quiet_message(STATUS "No Azure Kinect SDK found in ./ext/sdk")
    endif()
endif()

# On Linux, we might find k4a installed to the system path. Failing that, we can search the ext/sdk folder.
if(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")
    
    set(K4A_INSTALL_NEEDED FALSE)

    set(_exact_arg )
    if (FIND_VERSION_EXACT)
        set(_exact_arg EXACT)
    endif()

    set(_quiet_arg )
    if (FIND_QUIETLY)
        set(_quiet_arg QUIET)
    endif()

    set(_required_arg )
    if (FIND_REQUIRED)
        set(_required_arg REQUIRED)
    endif()

    # Linux is much easier: just check if k4a is installed to the system path
    find_package(k4a ${FIND_VERSION} ${_exact_arg} ${_quiet_arg} ${_required_arg} NO_MODULE)
    find_package(k4arecord ${FIND_VERSION} ${_exact_arg} ${_quiet_arg} ${_required_arg} NO_MODULE)

# On Windows, we will have to find K4A installed in Program Files. Failing that, we can search the ext/sdk folder.
elseif(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
    
    # Windows always needs installation
    set(K4A_INSTALL_NEEDED TRUE)

    # Get a list of SDK's installed in Program Files
    file(GLOB _sdk_dirs "C:/Program Files/Azure Kinect SDK*")

    set(_best_sdk_dir "")
    set(_best_sdk_version "0.0.0")

    foreach(_sdk_dir ${_sdk_dirs})

        unset(_version_file CACHE)
        find_file(_version_file "version.txt"
            PATHS ${_sdk_dir}
            NO_DEFAULT_PATH
        )

        if(NOT _version_file)
            quiet_message(WARNING "Azure Kinect SDK located at ${_sdk_dir} does not contain a version file. Skipping this SDK.")
            continue()
        endif()

        set(_version_file_contents "0.0.0")
        file(READ ${_version_file} _version_file_contents)

        if(${_version_file_contents} MATCHES "^([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)(-.+)?")
            set(_sdk_version "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}.${CMAKE_MATCH_2}.${CMAKE_MATCH_3}")
            set(_sdk_version_major "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
            set(_sdk_version_minor "${CMAKE_MATCH_2}")
            set(_sdk_version_patch "${CMAKE_MATCH_3}")

            quiet_message("Found Azure Kinect SDK located at ${_sdk_dir} with version ${_sdk_version}")

            # Now do the real logic. First, exact matches should take precedence (if requested)
            if (FIND_VERSION_EXACT)
                # If we found the exact version requested, no need to search any more
                if (_sdk_version VERSION_EQUAL FIND_VERSION)
                    set(_best_sdk_dir ${_sdk_dir})
                    set(_best_sdk_version ${_sdk_version})
                    break()
                endif()
            else()
                # Find the "best compatible version"
                # For K4A, this means:
                # - Major version must be the same as requested
                # - Minor version must be greater-than-or-equal requested
                # - Patch version must be greater-than-or-equal requested, but ONLY if Minor version equals the requested version
                
                # First check if this SDK is major-version compatible
                if (NOT (_sdk_version_major EQUAL FIND_VERSION_MAJOR))
                    quiet_message(STATUS "Rejecting SDK located at ${_sdk_dir}: Major version mismatch (found ${_sdk_version_major}, requested ${FIND_VERSION_MAJOR})")
                    continue()
                endif()

                # Next, check if minor version is greater than or equal requested
                if (NOT (_sdk_version_minor GREATER_EQUAL FIND_VERSION_MINOR))
                    quiet_message(STATUS "Rejecting SDK located at ${_sdk_dir}: Minor version too low (found ${_sdk_version_minor}, requested at least ${FIND_VERSION_MINOR})")
                    continue()
                endif()

                # If the _sdk_version_minor is greater than the FIND_VERSION_MINOR, we don't care about the patch version
                # since the patch version resets on a minor version upgrade
                if (_sdk_version_minor EQUAL FIND_VERSION_MINOR)
                    # Finally, check if patch version is greater than or equal requested
                    if (NOT (_sdk_version_patch GREATER_EQUAL FIND_VERSION_PATCH))
                        quiet_message(STATUS "Rejecting SDK located at ${_sdk_dir}: Patch version too low (found ${_sdk_version_patch}, requested at least ${FIND_VERSION_PATCH})")
                        continue()
                    endif()
                endif()

                # If we got here, the SDK is version compatible. Check if a better SDK version has already been selected
                if (_best_sdk_version VERSION_GREATER _sdk_version)
                    quiet_message(STATUS "Rejecting SDK located at ${_sdk_dir}: A more recent SDK has already been found (found ${_sdk_version}, already found ${_best_sdk_version})")
                    continue()
                endif()

                set(_k4a_lib_path "${_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_K4A_LIB_PATH}")
                if(NOT EXISTS "${_k4a_lib_path}")
                    quiet_message(WARNING "Rejecting SDK located at ${_sdk_dir}: Could not find k4a.lib at ${_k4a_lib_path}")
                    continue()
                endif()

                set(_k4arecord_lib_path "${_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_K4ARECORD_LIB_PATH}")
                if(NOT EXISTS "${_k4arecord_lib_path}")
                    quiet_message(WARNING "Rejecting SDK located at ${_sdk_dir}: Could not find k4arecord.lib at ${_k4arecord_lib_path}")
                    continue()
                endif()

                set(_k4a_bin_path "${_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_K4A_DLL_PATH}")
                if(NOT EXISTS "${_k4a_bin_path}")
                    quiet_message(WARNING "Rejecting SDK located at ${_sdk_dir}: Could not find k4a.dll at ${_k4a_bin_path}")
                    continue()
                endif()

                set(_k4arecord_bin_path "${_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_K4ARECORD_DLL_PATH}")
                if(NOT EXISTS "${_k4arecord_bin_path}")
                    quiet_message(WARNING "Rejecting SDK located at ${_sdk_dir}: Could not find k4arecord.dll at ${_k4arecord_bin_path}")
                    continue()
                endif()

                unset(_depthengine_bin)
                file(GLOB _depthengine_bin 
                    LIST_DIRECTORIES FALSE 
                    ${_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_BIN_DIR}/${DEPTHENGINE_GLOB})

                if(NOT _depthengine_bin)
                    quiet_message(WARNING "Rejecting SDK located at ${_sdk_dir}: Could not find a depth engine dll at ${_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_BIN_DIR}")
                    continue()
                endif()

                set(_best_sdk_version ${_sdk_version})
                set(_best_sdk_dir ${_sdk_dir})

            endif()

        else()
            quiet_message(WARNING "Could not parse SDK version found in ${_version_file}. Found version ${_version_file_contents}. Skipping this SDK.")
            continue()
        endif()

    endforeach()
    
    if (_best_sdk_version VERSION_EQUAL "0.0.0")

        set(_message_type WARNING)
        if (FIND_REQUIRED)
            set(_message_type FATAL_ERROR)
        endif()
        
        # Print this message if FIND_REQURIED since it is mandatory to produce a fatal error, or 
        # print a warning if we weren't asked to be quiet
        if(FIND_REQUIRED OR (NOT FIND_QUIETLY))
            message(${_message_type} "Could not find a compatible Azure Kinect Sensor SDK installed in Program Files")
        endif()

        return()
    endif()

    add_library(k4a::k4a SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)

    target_include_directories(
        k4a::k4a 
        INTERFACE
            ${_best_sdk_dir}/sdk/include
            ${_best_sdk_dir}/sdk/include/k4a
    )

    set_property(TARGET k4a::k4a PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS "")
    set_property(TARGET k4a::k4a PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${_best_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_K4A_DLL_PATH}")
    set_property(TARGET k4a::k4a PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${_best_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_K4A_LIB_PATH}")
    
    unset(_depthengine_bin)
    file(GLOB _depthengine_bin 
        LIST_DIRECTORIES FALSE 
        ${_best_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_BIN_DIR}/${DEPTHENGINE_GLOB})

    if(NOT _depthengine_bin)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "SDK was accepted without a depth engine!")
        return()
    endif()

    # Mark the depthengine as a requirement for running k4a.dll
    set_property(TARGET k4a::k4a PROPERTY IMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES "${_depthengine_bin}")
    
    add_library(k4a::k4arecord SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)

    target_include_directories(
        k4a::k4arecord 
        INTERFACE
            ${_best_sdk_dir}/sdk/include
            ${_best_sdk_dir}/sdk/include/k4arecord
    )
    
    set_property(TARGET k4a::k4arecord PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS "")
    set_property(TARGET k4a::k4arecord PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${_best_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_K4ARECORD_DLL_PATH}")
    set_property(TARGET k4a::k4arecord PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${_best_sdk_dir}/${RELATIVE_WIN_K4ARECORD_LIB_PATH}")
    
    set(${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FOUND TRUE)
    set(${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_VERSION ${_best_sdk_version})
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown host system: ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME}")
endif()
```

- the `FindModuleHelpers.cmake` called in Findk4a.cmake

```
function(print_variable x)
    message(STATUS "${x}: ${${x}}")
endfunction()

function(quiet_message)
    if(NOT FIND_QUIETLY)
        message(${ARGV})
    endif()
endfunction()

## Initialize some standardized variables
set(FIND_VERSION_COUNT ${${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FIND_VERSION_COUNT})
set(FIND_VERSION_EXACT ${${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FIND_VERSION_EXACT})
set(FIND_VERSION ${${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FIND_VERSION})
set(FIND_VERSION_MAJOR ${${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR})
set(FIND_VERSION_MINOR ${${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FIND_VERSION_MINOR})
set(FIND_VERSION_PATCH ${${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FIND_VERSION_PATCH})
set(FIND_QUIETLY ${${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FIND_QUIETLY})
set(FIND_REQUIRED ${${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FIND_REQUIRED})
```

Could you help me? It is really frustrating to not be able to code because I cannot call the functions properly.